# Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux, semi-new to React. I've made a few simple applications with it. I understand the basic concept of Redux (storing state in a central location) which sounds more elegant than passing things along via components/props.

However, I am getting the following error:

Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

```
onSubmit
src/containers/Login.js:28
  25 | 
  26 | const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  27 |   onSubmit: (username, password) => {
> 28 |     dispatch(login(username, password))
  29 |   }
  30 | })
  31 | 

LoginForm._this.onSubmit
src/components/LoginForm.js:29
  26 | 
  27 | onSubmit = (event) => {
  28 |   event.preventDefault()
> 29 |   this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username, this.state.password)
  30 | }
  31 | 
  32 | render() {
```

As you can see, there appears to be an issue with the dispatch line in Login.js.

Login.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm'
import {login} from  '../actions/auth'
import {authErrors, isAuthenticated} from '../reducers'

const Login = (props) => {
  if(props.isAuthenticated) {
     return  <Redirect to='/' />
  }

  return (
     <div className="login-page">
       <LoginForm {...props}/>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  errors: authErrors(state),
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onSubmit: (username, password) => {
    dispatch(login(username, password))
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

My guess based on what I've been googling is that I'm not actually missing any sort of type data, but there's actually probably a problem somewhere in my middleware.

What might be going on? How would I troubleshoot this or interpret it?

EDIT - here's my login function:

```
export const login = (username, password) => ({
  [RSAA]: {
    endpoint: '/api/auth/token/obtain/',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    types: [
      LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain 'boilerplate' that we need to follow when using redux. Based on the error message, it simply means `dispatch` action is expecting an object with `type` property

```
dispatch({ type: 'ACTION_TYPE', .... });
```

so depending on what `login(username, password)` return, `redux` `dispatch` will expect an object with `property` type

Comment: Hrm. I'll add what the login function says - I will admit, I found this in a tutorial for what I want to do, so it may not be set correctly.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: Very simple, do a console log right before dispatch. `console.log(login(username, password));` and see what it says

Comment: Hrm, the object returned seems to have types, though. @@redux-api-middleware/RSAA: body: "{"username":"fdsfdsdfs","password":"fdssdfdfs"}"endpoint: "/api/auth/token/obtain/"headers: {Content-Type: "application/json"}method: "POST"types: (3) ["@@auth/LOGIN_REQUEST", "@@auth/LOGIN_SUCCESS", "@@auth/LOGIN_FAILURE"]}

Comment: but dispatch action is expecting a plain JS object, so perhaps you can massage it before dispatch?

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I'll go check out the Redux documentation and try to format it correctly.

Comment: That sounds as if you're using a specific library called [`redux-api-middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware), but haven't actually added the middleware itself to your Redux store setup process.

Comment: @markerikson - I am using that, and that does sound like a promising solution. I will test and get back to you.